# Integrating stripe payments (JS and PHP) with a custom amount (JS variable)

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I've been trying to figure this out for days with no luck.
I'm trying to implement Stripe Payments Checkout into my website.  The payment amount is on the payments page as a JS variable.  I was able to get Basic Checkout working, but apparently that can't use a custom amount, or send any data to the PHP processing page (email, and some order attributes).  I've been trying to use the Custom Checkout but I can't figure it out.  Any help?

So far I have this in config.php:

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$stripe = array(
"secret_key"      => "MY SECRET KEY IS HERE",
"publishable_key" => "MY PUBLISHED KEY IS HERE"
);

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);
?>
```

and this is in a file called process.php:

```
<?php
require_once('./config.php');

$token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];
$input = $_POST["totalprice"];
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
  'email' => 'customer@example.com',
  'source'  => $token
));

$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  'customer' => $customer->id,
  'amount'   => $input,
  'currency' => 'usd'
));

echo $input;
?>
```

And in the initial PHP file I have:

```
<?php require_once('./config.php'); ?>
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
<script
src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
data-key="MY PUBLIC TEST KEY IS HERE"
data-amount= amt * 100
data-name="Test Name"
data-description="Widget"
data-image="/img/logo.jpg"
data-locale="auto"
>
<form type=hidden name="totalprice" value=amt*100 action="process.php" method="POST">
</script>
</form>
```

With that said though, I've had a bunch of other code I've tried before that hasn't worked, so this current code probably should be scrapped.  I'd really appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 0):

Well, following is the sample code of Custom Integration.

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

<button id="customButton">Purchase</button>

<script>
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh',
  image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
  locale: 'auto',
  token: function(token) {
    // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
    // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
  }
});

document.getElementById('customButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // Open Checkout with further options:
  handler.open({
    name: 'Stripe.com',
    description: '2 widgets',
    zipCode: true,
    amount: 2000
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Close Checkout on page navigation:
window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
  handler.close();
});
</script>
```

The source code is given on [this page](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom)

So is that what you are looking for?